# Using a background step like an Outline Step

Tags: c#, .net, automation, specflow

I would like to be able to define a set of run rules that will run for every scenario in the file. and the easiest place to put these would be in the background but they would need to have an examples table much like a scenario outline.

```
    Feature: Example Feature File
    In order to perform as task 
    As I user 
    I want this test to work 

Background: 
 Given I have used <data> in my test 
 Examples: 
 | data           | 
 | test string    | 
 | test String  2 | 


Scenario Outline: Running a test
Given I have prepared the test data 
When I run the test 
Then The test should pass
```

Can anyone think of a way i can make this work ( or something similar) as ive got over 200 tests and im a little loathed to add this to each one of them

Comment: Unfortunately you need to put this in each scenario. You cannot provide example data for the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you need to put this in each scenario. You cannot provide example data for the background.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is using  `createSet` and `createInstance` in background. If you have data in tables , you can use [assist helpers](https://specflow.org/documentation/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers/) . They both support table structure and you can use them in `Background`

The other way is to implement above table in `Beforescenario` hook . You can further categorize using [tag scoping](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks)

In both cases , you will have to implement passing data using properties or context or some other way. You can read about [featureContext](https://specflow.org/documentation/FeatureContext/)

While implementing, keep in mind though that `Background` will run before first step in each scenario but after any `Before` hook

Imo, it is still worth implementing even if it takes a bit more effort than having to include data in each scenario.