# Specflow using Background with Example table?

Tags: automated-tests, specflow

Is there any way to use example like this?

```
Background:
Given user is logged in and and enter empty solution with name: <"p">
And user is on the loged page

Example:
| p |
| portfolio1 |
```

I get
`expected: #EOF, #TableRow, #DocStringSeparator, #StepLine, #TagLine, #ScenarioLine, #RuleLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Example:'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a background step like an Outline Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992647/using-a-background-step-like-an-outline-step)

Comment: @Ganit: Why do you want to have examples for the background